# Transfer only original images to new site

Tags: images, export

I'm rebuilding a site on a working directory. It's an older page and I thought I'd take this opportunity to clean out Uploads. The site has had 3-4 themes and each one has spat out 4-6 resized images for each original image (image150x150.jpg etc). I've tried a couple of plugins to clean out these unused resized images, but they've always proved disastrous. Is there a way to export ONLY the original images and leave all that resized junk behind? Or maybe only transfer featured images (the only images currently attached)? thanks!